# How to open jQuery UI dialog in page with master page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I want to open a jQuery UI Dialog from a asp.net page with master page. In a page within master page the code works fine but with master page doesn't work.

The code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"   MasterPageFile="~/privado/master/interior.master" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.vb" Inherits="ProyectoDemo.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headInterior" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"    rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="Styles/addhunters.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui- 1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo page css*/
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration:  none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    </style>    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contenidoInterior" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Dialog      
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancelar": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            // Dialog Link
            $('#Boton').click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="uno">
        <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>        
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="prueba" ></asp:TextBox>
        <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>              
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Boton" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <!-- ui-dialog -->
        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
            <p>Dialog text</p>            
        </div>  
    </div>
```

I think the problem is how to refer to "dialog" within placeholder. I tried with several ways but I don't find the solution.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Javier

Comment: Can you please put the output of the page into http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: are you sure you are not loading jQuery also in the masterpage? Yet, you got to wrap your `$(function...` within a `$(document).ready(...` call, so jQuery will only call it when all the page dom is ok.

Comment: I have this code in master page <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> I must be remove from master page and put this code in child page?

Comment: You need to remove <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> from the page - only one jQuery allowed in the output

Comment: So you are loading jQuery twice... depends on what you need, if you need jquery for all pages that uses your masterpage, then remove the loading of jQuery in the child and leave it in the master. But if this is the only childpage that uses jQuery, the remove the loading of jQuery from the master.

Comment: I removed this line but I have the same error message "the object does not support this property or method"... Also I insert " $(document).ready($(function () {" but doesn't work :-(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you need to consider:

1. Add following code to a separate common.js and add it's reference to master page:

```
window["common"] = {
    liveDialog: function(btnId) {
         $(btnId).live(click,common.showDialog);
         return false;
    },
    showDialog() : function(){
         $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancelar": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

    }

}
```

1. Add following method to master page:

```
public void RegisterDialog(clientBtnId)
{
    this.page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(),"__registerDialg","common.liveDialog('"+clientBtnId+"');",true);
}
```

1. From your content page, cast this.MasterPage to actual class name of your master page and pass your button's clientId to RegisterDialog.

--edited example --

For example your master page class name is CustomSiteMaster, you can write `((CustomSiteMaster)this.Master).RegisterDialog(button1.ClientID);`
-- end of edit --

It will work without problem

Comment: I don't understand the step 2 "From your content page..." please, could you explain me more deeply?

Comment: I must insert ((CustomSiteMaster)this.Master).RegisterDialog(button1.ClientID); in Page_Load method?... I'm using vb.net, could you send me the code in vb.net?...

Answer (score 0):

Add to LinkButton OnClientClick property as below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Boton" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="$('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false;" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Also, if you want to select server-side control by id use following selector syntax:

```
$("#<%= ControlID.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: Thank you Yuriy but doesn't work... I have this js error message: "the object does not support this property or method"

Comment: Did you post exactly the same markup? Does the "dialog" div marked with runat="server" attribute? Try to set autoOpen property to true. Does dialog opened in that case? Also check url for jQuery-UI library. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, I insert exactly your code... Not, "dialog" div haven't any runat="server" attribute. With autoOpen in true I have the same situation. Finally, the url for jQuery-UI is ok... :(. I have to send the code by private e-mail, could you help me with this issue?...

Answer (score 0):

To find any control in content place holder please make sure to use the syntax like this:

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolderId_ControlId')
```

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer but in this case, I try to find "dialog" div but I still the same error message "the object does not support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is not being loaded because your `src` attribute has a additional space in it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui- 1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Just change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And jQuery UI might load fine and you will stop receiving `"the object does not support this property or method"` messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution to the "mistery". The problem is very simple. The references to .js files of jQuery-UI are in Conten1 placeholder, I put this two lines in Conten2 placeholder, this content has a javascript function in order to open the dialog.

The complete and working code is the following:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"   MasterPageFile="~/privado/master/interior.master" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.vb"   Inherits="ProyectoDemo.WebForm3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headInterior" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"    rel="stylesheet" />  
    <link href="Styles/addhunters.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--<%@ MasterType  VirtualPath="~/privado/master/Interior.master"%>--%>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo page css*/
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration:    none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position:   absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0;   cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    </style>    
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="contenidoInterior" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-   1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hola');
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancelar": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#MainContent_contenidoInterior_Boton').click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });               
    </script>

    <div id="uno" >
        <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>        
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="prueba" ></asp:TextBox>
        <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>              
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Boton" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <!-- ui-dialog -->
        <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
            <p>Dialog text</p>            
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Javier